# Вывод даты из Mysql с типом Varchar

Tags: php, mysql

имеется таблица user

```
int | varchar | varchar

id  | name    | last_visit

13  | Гоша    | 12.05.2017 15:30
14  | Тоша    | 10.05.2017 12:31
и т.д.
```

Можно ли как-то вытащить данные из этой таблицы чтобы в запросе сделать выборку, где Last_Visit, например, сегодня. Без учитывания времени.

Грубый пример: where `last_visit`='12.05.2017'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Преобразуйте last_visit к date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
WHERE str_to_date(last_visit,'%d.%m.%Y')='20170512'
```

Пример - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9debe/13